# update view from another one the same viewmodel

Tags: dialog, view, mvvm-light

I am new to the MVVM philosophy, and my question may be stupid but hey, I try anyway.

I have a view associated with a model view. In this view, I open a dialog box when the user presses a button.

From this dialog box, I want to refresh the main view without closing the dialog.

The dialog and the main view share the same view model, and I have a property that is binded in the main view.

But when I change the binded property from from the dialog, it is well updated, but not the main view.

Here some code:

MainView.xaml:

`<TextBox x:Name="tnNomModele" 
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                         Height="23" 
                         Margin="142,35,0,0" 
                         TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                         VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                         Width="143" 
                         Text="{Binding MyProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>`

ViewModel.cs
    `public string MyProperty
{
get
            {
                return _mystring ;
            }
            set
            {
                _mystring  = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("MyProperty");
            }
        }`

Here's how I call the dialog, on the command binded with a button on the main view:
`MyDialog diag = new MyDialog ();
diag.ShowDialog();`

And in the command binded with a button on the dialog, I change the value of MyProperty.

But nothing happens in the main view...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your binding:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tnNomModele" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="142,35,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="143" Text="{Binding MyProperty,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

The change is that you're using the default Binding mode, which is OneWay.  This means that the ViewModel can push changes to the View but will not receieve changes made from the View.  Using TwoWay means that the ViewModel receives notifications from the View when a property changes.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Finally, the component I used had a MVVM version, but it was to instable, so I cancel the use of MVVM....sadly...